# First() taking time in linq

Tags: c#, linq

1) When i use without First() it's take **8ms** sec

```
IEnumerable<string> Discriptionlist = (from lib in ProgramsData.Descendants("program")
                         where lib.Attribute("TMSId").Value == TMSIds 
                         select lib.Element("descriptions").Element("desc").Value);
```

2) With First() it's take **248ms** sec

```
string Discriptionlist = (from lib in ProgramsData.Descendants("program")
                         where lib.Attribute("TMSId").Value == TMSIds 
                         select lib.Element("descriptions").Element("desc").Value).First();
```

Data reading use

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(FilePath))
{
    Xdoc = XDocument.Load(sr);
}
```

Any solution or another way for reducing the time (It take less than 248ms ) and also get the result in a string.? Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear, the first example (without the `.First()`) isn't actually querying the data.

Comment: In the first case, no query is actually executed, it only builds the query which is not run until actual data is requested by `.First()` `.ToList()` etc.

Comment: That said, to answer your question, I'd suggest the problem's with either the effort involved in filtering the data (the `where`) or access to the data source itself is slow. How large is your XML document? Let's start there.

Comment: Please provide the values of `sr` and `TSMIds`

Comment: I'm also not sure 248 ms is a long time to parse a reasonably sized XML document.  Maybe you want to cache the parsing?

Comment: Not sure if this will be optimized to stop parsing after the first hit. Maybe a sophisticated XPath would be faster? (Really not sure, just an idea)

Comment: @Hogan, TMSIds is a string value. it use for find maching string.

Comment: Of course it is Ankit -- I also asked for the XML if we see that we could understand if this is slow or not.

Comment: My XML file size is **521MB**. When i remove unneeded xml node from XML file than use second query. it's not take time. Maybe  that's way FIRST() is take time

Comment: I remove the linq code of my project and use the foreach to get all needed data. that its work for me

Answer (score 3):

The first statement just creates an IEnumerable, the actual query runs only when you start enumerating. The second statement runs the enumeration, that's why it's slower.

You'll notice the same thing with the same statement if you run this:

```cs
string DiscriptionListStr;
foreach(var a in Discriptionlist)
{
  DiscriptionListStr = a;
  break;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, at all.

Comment: I would disagree. There's no point in reducing the time it takes when there's nothing to compare against. The root issue is the misunderstanding on how LINQ works.

Comment: Try this but foreach take time and also try Discriptionlist.First() both are take time

Comment: I don't see how this answers, "Any solution or another way for reduce time and also get result in string?" It does answer, "Why is the second code slower than the first?" or "How can I make the first code as slow as the second?" fine though.

Answer (score 1):

Linq uses a "feature" called lazy loading.   What this means in practice is that in certain cases a linq expression will not actually do anything.  It is just ready to do something when asked.  So you have ask for an element it will then perform the action to get the next element at that time.

Since your first statement does not ask for an element the database is not even queried.  In your second you ask for the First element the query has to run.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't answer the question, and that's already been covered (twice) in the comments. It's more of an aside.

Comment: Just to be explicit, I think @JayMee is talking about this: _"Any solution or another way **for reduce time and also get result in string**?"_ (emphasis by me)

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ -- I think it does answer the question -- the question (as I understood it) is -- here is an example of it being fast, here is an example of it being slow -- how can I make the slow one faster.

Comment: @Hogan Exactly. Your answer covers the "why is it perceived slow" part. Not the "how to make it fast" part. I guess, that's what JayMee is referring to.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ To answer the other question we would need to see what the XML is and what all the other variables are.

Comment: Correct, I'm referring to the actual question, not the misunderstanding of how linq works.

Comment: @Hogan - then we should ask for those details in the comments instead of suggesting an answer that doesn't quite cover it all.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ -- :D I did so